# How should unix application log huge amounts of data?

Tags: logs, syslog

I'm worried that my application might produce huge amounts of logs for some users.

- What should I take into consideration so that usability is not hampered (support rolling etc.)?
- Is there a standard way for an application to query logging level configuration (so that no resources are wasted to write to disabled logger)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to produce a huge amount of data at any priority other than `debug`, it's best if your default configuration to log to a file rather than to the system logs, or at the very least offer this possibility. If these logs are debugging logs, they should be off by default, and printed out only if your application is invoked with an option (on the command line or in a configuration file) to tell it to print debugging logs.

If it's obvious from the purpose of your application that it'll produce a lot of logs, that's ok.

You can't reliably query the logging level configuration from the application side. Some systems log remotely, for example; then the configuration would be on another machine. Even if it's on the same machine, a non-root user might not have the permission to read the logging configuration. If your application can be configured to produce either reasonable or huge amounts of logs, it's up to the application configuration to determine this.

If you log through the syslog facility, you don't need to do anything to support log rotation. If you log to a file, you need to provide a way for the application to close and reopen its log file. You can use SIGUSR1 or SIGUSR2 for this, or even SIGHUP if you don't use it as a termination signal (for daemons, i.e. programs which aren't run from a terminal, SIGHUP normally means “reload your configuration”, which can include reopening a log file). The log rotation program will first move the log to a different name, then send the signal to tell your application to create a new log file.